# Can a non-trivial subgroup have negative elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, cyclic-groups

Lets say we have a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{13}$ and we have found the following subgroup $\langle 3\rangle$.

Now we calculate the following:

\begin{align}3^1 \pmod{13} &= 3,\\
3^2  \pmod{13}&= 9 \pmod{13} \equiv -4 \pmod{13} = -4,\\
3^3 \pmod{13}& = 3\times(-4) \pmod{13} = -12 \pmod{13} = 1.\end{align}

As you can see the inverse of $-4$ is $9$, but my question is the final set of elements going to be like this:

$\langle 3\rangle = \{3,-4,1\}$ or like this: $\langle 3\rangle = \{3,9,1\}$.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: $\overline9=\overline{-4}$ are the same set.  There's really no such thing as "negative" in a cyclic group.

Comment: You mean that the *additive* inverse of $\;4\pmod{13}\;$ is $\;9\pmod{13}\;$ . The elements $\;-4\pmod{13}\;$ and $\;9\pmod{13}\;$ are one and the same element in $\;\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z=:\Bbb Z_{13}\;$ . Thus, both sets you ask about at the end of your question are exactly the samte.  BTW, very recommended to use MathJax to write mathematics in this site

Answer (score 2):

Actually the residue classes partition the set of integers.  When it comes to $\Bbb Z_{13}$, there are thirteen residue classes.  *Every* integer is in exactly one of these classes.  Which representative you use (for each equivalence class) is up to you.  You could always pick a negative integer if you like.

Typically you will see $\Bbb Z_{13}=\{0,1,\dots,12\}$.  Here it is understood,  for instance,  that $\bar2=\{2+13k: k\in\Bbb Z\}$.  That is,  these numbers are all identified.   So, again, the elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ are actually equivalence classes.  Also, the $"\bar{}"$ is often just skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The group ${\Bbb Z}_{13}^*$ is a subset of the ring ${\Bbb Z}_{13}=\{0,1,\ldots,12\}$ whose elements are the residue classes modulo 13. Here $-4\equiv 9\mod 13$ and so $-4$ and $9$ represent the same element.